# How to change wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 to 32-bit on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, arduino

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 64-bit

I've been working on a small project using Arduino IDE v 1.8.13 installed via snap. I'm running into an error while trying to flash the Soft Device:

`Error while flashing SoftDevice.`

`ERROR: ld.so: object '/snap/arduino/41/lib/bindtextdomain.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64)`

Would anyone have a suggestion to try?

Comment: I would try using the non-snap version of Arduino IDE, try flashing an example project of the IDE, try flashing the compiled binary using avrdude, or whatever flashing tool your device requires, from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add 32-bit support to 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04. Use the following commands

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

After that try installing the 32 bit libraries, if any required. The most common 32-bit libraries can be installed using the following command

```
sudo apt install ia32-libs
```

Comment: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt dist-upgrade`
Nothing resulted

Then:

max-power@max-power:~$ sudo apt install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate

Should I try lib32z1 ?

Comment: @Carbon I wrote these commands in the answer. Does it solve your issue?

Comment: I added more to the comment. I hit return too soon.

Comment: I just tried `sudo apt install lib32z1`. It installed 4 new packages. I rebooted. update. dist-upgrade. Started arduino. Still the same error.

Comment: I ran `~$ dpkg --print-architecture`. It resulted 
`amd64`. It seems to the command to enable 32-bit architecture has changed maybe?

Comment: I then ran `~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`. It resulted
`i386`. Starting to get somewhere now... fingers-crossed

Comment: `~$ objdump -p /snap/arduino/41/lib/bindtextdomain.so | grep NEEDED`
  `NEEDED               libdl.so.2`
  `NEEDED               libc.so.6`; No idea if I have these but looking...